# Removing "a" symbol from colour legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I keep getting this `a` on my colour legend when I make this graph in GGPLOT2.

```
ggplot(sher_ei_si, aes(SI, EI, shape = crop, label = treatment, colour =
        management)) +
        geom_point() +
        geom_text_repel(aes(SI, EI)) +
        xlim(0, 100) +
        ylim(0, 100) +
        labs(x = "Structure", y = "Enrichment", shape = "Crop", colour =
            "Management") +
        geom_vline(xintercept = 50) +
        geom_hline(yintercept = 50) +
        scale_colour_manual(values = c("grey0", "grey60")
```

Plot showing `a` under colour legend
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For exact output generation, please provide the input data.*

---

You can use `show.legend = FALSE` to exclude the `a` symbol from your example:

```
geom_text_repel(aes(SI, EI), show.legend = FALSE)
```